# Update List Fragment inside a viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've Lists in viewpager. I want to update lists content in some fragments in viepager. I've already tried many snippet of codes online but nothing worked!

What I want. When an event occurs. I want to update some of the lists in viewpager without recreating the whole viewpager to reflect changes. Actually, I've tried to setTag for fragments and used the following snippet of code:
http://semycolon.blogspot.in/2014/12/refresh-pageviewer-fragment-everytime.html

But when i try to call notifyDataSetChange() on list adapter in the fragment. I get a NullPointerException.

Any solutions?

My code almost the same as in the above link. So there is no need to post my own.

Comment: I am currently working on same issue. In my app I have three tabs in tablayout inside of viewpager. I pass new items from parent activity to the listadapter, enable/disable specific items and after that call `((SimpleAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Comment: @IgorBljahhin
Actually. The main point I am stuck in is how to set tags for all fragments in viewpager?

Comment: Did you find the solution for tags?

Comment: I found the solution with EventBus. I send the position of page to the fragment when it's created and store it in its bundle. I create an event class that has the new list and the position of the affected list. Then I post an event with the position and the new list. In the fragment I check i the @Subscribe method if the position comes from event equals to the the one stored in the current ListFragment object then I call notifyDataSetChange!